# Contact form to not load new page

Tags: php

I currently have a contact form which i have more or less copied from a tutorial online. When the form is submitted however it reloads the page. Would it be possible to amend the below code to send the form but not reload the page?

```
<?php
$mail_to = 'benliger@hotmail.com'; // specify your email here

// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
$name = $_POST['sender_name'];
$mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];
$phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];
$message = $_POST['sender_message'];

// Construct email subject
$subject = 'enquiry ' . $name;

// Construct email body
$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;

// Construct email headers
$headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thanks for getting in touch!');
    window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message not sent :( Please, get in contact with me directly: benliger@hotmail.com');
   window.location = 'index.php';
</script>
<?php
}
?>


<form action="form_process.php" method="POST"> 

<label for="field_name">Name:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_email">E-mail:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_email" name="sender_email"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_phone">Phone:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_message">Message:</label> 

<textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message"></textarea> 

<br /><br />   

<input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Send"> 

</form>
```

Comment: I dont see a form...

Comment: Get rid of `window.location = 'index.php';`

Comment: This isn't complete code, so it's difficult to provide *exact* advice.  But if you don't want any page loads/refreshes at all then you want to use AJAX to send your form data to the server.  Then in response to that AJAX request you would update the page elements to indicate success or failure.

Comment: sorry I have added the form code now. Is there any other way to do this without Ajax? Its not the end of the world but would be great if they could just stay on the page they were on. Also @JohnConde I tried removing that but it then takes me to the PHP page just by itself (currently the PHP page is being pulled into a div of a wider page)

Comment: if it helps aswell here is the URL http://benliger.webatu.com/

Comment: how exactly would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you want to submit a form without refreshing the page you can use AJAX. And if you also want to `alert` the message that you provide from your PHP you can `echo` the message and `alert` it with your AJAX call. Try the code below, i added comments between the lines for explanation.

```
<?php

//Check if POST data is set, and not empty, else it will do this every single time, submitted or not
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{

    $mail_to = 'benliger@hotmail.com'; // specify your email here

    // Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
    $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
    $mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];
    $phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];
    $message = $_POST['sender_message'];

    // Construct email subject
    $subject = 'enquiry ' . $name;

    // Construct email body
    $body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;

    // Construct email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

    $mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_sent == true){ 
        //Echo the message now, because it will be catched in your jQuery listerener (see code below)
        echo 'Thanks for getting in touch!';
     } else { 
        //Echo the message now, because it will be catched in your jQuery listerener (see code below)
        echo 'Message not sent :( Please, get in contact with me directly: benliger@hotmail.com';
    }
    //This exit; is important, else the alert box will be full of the further html code
    exit;

}
?>


<form action="form_process.php" method="POST"> 

<label for="field_name">Name:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_email">E-mail:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_email" name="sender_email"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_phone">Phone:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_message">Message:</label> 

<textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message"></textarea> 

<br /><br />   

<input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Send"> 

</form>

<!-- Add jQuery library !-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    //Create listener for form
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
        //Prevent the default action
        e.preventDefault();

        //Define submitted form
        var form = $(this);

        //Create an array of input values
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        //Do the ajax request
        $.post('index.php',data,function(responseMessage){
            //Call resetForm function
            resetForm(form); 
            //Alert your message
            alert(responseMessage);
        });

    });

    //Reset form function
    function resetForm($form) {
        //Find input fields and set value to '' (empty);
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        //Find check- and radiobox and uncheck them;
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }   

</script>
```

Comment: Hmm i tried that but the problem is its still taking me to a blank page that says thanks for getting in touch! As mentioned in one of my comments above the contact.php page is actually being pulled into a div on a wider page, not sure if this helps you a bit...

Comment: Did you used the HTML form and PHP code in the same page? If you copy/paste this in one file `index.php` this code will work..

Comment: it still refreshes the page when i do, I pasted it in one file (the contact.php file) as theres where all the content for that page sits

Comment: Did you also changed `index.php` in `contact.php` in `$.post('index.php',data,function(responseMessage)`?

Comment: yes i did but it still reloads the page. I have added your code live into the page if you want to see what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: After i pasted the code into the index.php file rather than loading it into the index.php file through jquery after clicking on the contact button it works fine, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: one more question i have is how could i clear the form once its been submitted?

Comment: Ben, i updated my question. It shows how you can clear the form after submitting.